# Apply mute to CMSampleBuffer in Swift5

Tags: swift, xcode, cmsamplebuffer

I'm trying to save captured video & audio through a camera and mic on an iOS device using AVAssetWriter. I finished developing a basic function like a user can record both image(video) and audio using CMSampleBuffer, and now I'm trying to make the mute function available. I guess while `isMuted` is true, I need to append empty (or silent?) `CMSampleBuffer` to `assetWriterAudioInput`, but is that right approach? If not could you point me in the right direction? Also, in `createSilenceBuffer` function, how can I create empty/slient CMSampleBuffer?

```
var isMuted: Bool = false
var assetWriterAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if output == videoOutput {
        guard assetWriterVideoInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true else { return }
        assetWriterVideoInput?.append(sampleBuffer)
    } else if output == audioOutput {
        if issued {
            let silenceBuffer = createSilenceBuffer(from sampleBuffer)
            assetWriterAudioInput?.append(silenceBuffer)
        } else {
            assetWriterAudioInput?.append(sampleBuffer)
        }
    }
}

func createSilenceBuffer(from sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> CMSampleBuffer {
    // return new CMSampleBuffer without audio??
}
```

Comment: you could try _not_ passing any audio to `assetWriterAudioInput` while muted. that might do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this func to mute incoming audio `CMSampleBuffers`

```
private func _cacheAudioBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, isMuted: Bool) {
   if isMuted,
   let ref = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
    CMBlockBufferFillDataBytes(
        with: 0,
        blockBuffer: ref,
        offsetIntoDestination: 0,
        dataLength: CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(ref))
   }
       // Continue here with muted samplebuffer
}
```